# Global variable counting

Tags: javascript

I'm counting how many times when math > 5, It right now is counting up, but when math < 5, I want monkey to reset to 0. Then it will start counting again from 0.

```
    var monkey = 0;

function Normal() {

    var math = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    if (math >= 5) {
        monkey++;
        console.log(monkey);
    } else {

        console.log("We")
    }
}

<button onclick="Normal()">Hello</button>
```

Comment: So put `monkey = 0` in your else block.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JosiahKeller Maybe math >= 5 change to math > 5 can help a bit as well :)

Comment: @JosiahKeller That doesn't work, it just returns NaN

Comment: @user5544792 Show the code that's doing that.

Comment: @user5544792 `monkey=0` not `var monkey=0`, you don't want to define a new local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed reset for monkey

```
var monkey = 0;

function Normal() {

    var math = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    if (math >= 5) {
        monkey++;
        console.log(monkey);
    } else {
        monkey = 0;
        console.log("We")
    }
}

<button onclick="Normal()">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I accidentally added var to the else part.